# How can I construct std::pair<const K&, U&>?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a custom `Pair` class. (the reason is `std::pair<U,V>` isn't trivially copyable even if both `U` and `V` are trivially copyable)

The class is very simple:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
concept MemCopyable = std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, T> &&
    std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> && (sizeof(T) % alignof(T) == 0);

template <MemCopyable K, MemCopyable V> struct MyPair {
  K first;
  V second;
};
```

That's all.

I need the following conversion operator: `MyPair<K, V>` to `std::pair<const K&, V&>`

I've tried several attempts but all failed, including these:

```
operator std::pair<const K&, V&> () const noexcept {
  return {first, second};
}
```

```
operator std::pair<const K&, V&> () const noexcept {
  return {std::cref(first), std::ref(second)};
}
```

```
operator std::pair<const K&, V&> () const noexcept {
  return std::pair<const K&, V&>{first, second};
}
```

```
operator std::pair<const K&, V&> () const noexcept {
  return std::pair<const K&, V&>(std::cref(first), std::ref(second));
}
```

```
operator std::pair<const K&, V&> () const noexcept {
  return std::pair<const K&, V&>(std::cref(first).get(), std::ref(second).get());
}
```

What's the correct way to typecast this?

Comment: Your `const` conversion operator is making `second` be considered `const` too.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica You're right, so I removed ```const``` and made a two version (```const``` and ```non-const```), but the compiler complains again for both operators now

Comment: That's a different question then

Comment: This works for me on MSVC: `operator std::pair<const K&, V&>() noexcept { return { first, second };}`  (just 1 non-const version. You cannot have a const version as noted above by  @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica).